# How to make my db variables global for my class (php)

Tags: php, class, variables, mysqli

I'm a rookie coder and i'm confused. I'm writing a simple code which gets some data from mysql db and posts it on  my CMS (umi cms) webpage. The thing is that cms wants me to put this code into a custom module (.php file which contains new class where i need to create my functions) . I did it but it doesn't look elegant because i'd want  to make db connecton variables to be class global, and secure. In future i'm going to write some more functions here which will use db connection. Here's my module class file and my 2 functions at the bottom lib() and getlib(). What would you suggest? somehow only return method working to output data in the targets div

```
    class modulelements extends def_module {
public $per_page;

public function __construct() {
parent::__construct();

//module default code
}
//module default functions
// here are my functions: ))

 public function lib ($template = "default", $per_page = false) {

$begin = "<table>
     <tr> 
        <td>Название</td>
             <td>Автор</td> 
                <td>Год</td>
                    <td>Число экземпляров</td>
                        <td>Выдано</td>
                     </tr> " . $this->getlib() ;

$stop = mysqli_close($conn) . "</table>" ;

return $begin . $stop ;
}

public function getlib() {
$servername = "server";
$username = "name";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "jum";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT name, author, year, number, towhom FROM lib";
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$stop = mysqli_close($conn) ;
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$outlib = Array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row into a string
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $outlib[] = "<tr> 
                            <td> ". $row["name"] . " </td> 
                                <td>". $row["author"]. "</td>
                                     <td> ". $row["year"] ."</td>
                                         <td>". $row["number"]. "</td>
                                            <td>". $row["towhom"].  "</td>
                                        </tr> "  ;
         } 
    $string=implode("",$outlib);
return $string;
} else {
    return "0 results";
}
}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make variables accessible everywhere in your class, just define them outside of your functions. You can make them private if you don't want them to be accessible outside your class:

```
class modulelements extends def_module {
    private $servername = "server";
    private $username = "name";
    private $password = "pass";
    private $dbname = "jum";
}
```

You can then access these values anywhere in your class using this eg.

```
$this->servername
```

If they will be the same for all instances of the class, you can use [class constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php):

```
const SERVERNAME = "server";
```

You can then access this using self:

```
self::SERVERNAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make those variables `$servername`, `$username`, `$password` and `$dbname` [constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php).

Include the following code in a file, let's say `database_config.php` and require it where necessary:

```
<?php

define("SERVERNAME", "server");
define("USERNAME", "name");
define("PASSWORD", "pass");
define("DBNAME", "jum");
```

Then you could use them like this:

```
<?php
require 'database_config.php';
$conn = mysqli_connect(SERVERNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DBNAME);
```

**LE**

Taken from php.net website of constant manual:

> Like superglobals, the scope of a constant is global. You can access
>   constants anywhere in your script without regard to scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can define them inside the class as constants:

```
class foo {
   const servername = "server";
    ....
//Or retrieve them by a function
   function getServername() { return self::servername; }
}
```

And use them from anywhere:

```
$fooObject = new foo();
$server = $fooObject::servername;
$server = $fooObject->getServername();
```

More info:  [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php)